# how add/modify standalone.xml in remote wildfly 8,9 openshift

Tags: openshift, wildfly

I trying find file standalone.xml in remote access in openshift in wildfly 8 and wildfly 9 too, but not result.

I found page: http://blog.arungupta.me/wildfly-custom-standalone-configuartion-file-openshift/ where described where should find the location of the file, but it is not there.

my console files:
[image]

is there any ways, how use own configuration xml ?

Answer (score 1):

Openshift Online allows you to override the default standalone.xml from your app by placing a file in your apps repository. The location is slightly different for v3 as it was for v2.

#### Overriding standalone.xml in Openshift Online v3

Place the file with your override in

```
/cfg/standalone.xml
```

#### Overriding standalone.xml in Openshift Online v2

Place the file with your override in

```
/.openshift/config/standalone.xml
```

Comment: Where is this documented? I have not been able to find this searching Openshift v3 docs.

Comment: @MichaelEdgar Sorry there is no source as I pieced this together from tutorials / examples. They should improve the docs on this.

Answer (score 0):

Look for `standalone.xml` in `%WILDFLY_HOME%\standalone\configuration`. There you should find `standalone.xlm` and also `standalone-full.xml` and `standalone-full-ha.xml` (if you want to also drive your wildfly in different mode).

Comment: yes, but after restart wildfly, all settings are restore to basic configuraton

Comment: That is as expected since all your changes have to be replicable. So you have to change your cartrige/image (in OpenShift v3) or your scritps in OS2 to update the configuration before deployment of the cartrige/image